# Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed.( In combination with classes referring to each other.)

Tags: c++, user-interface, pointers

I am stuck with something and I seem to keep running against different problems over and over again. It should be pretty simple, I just don't know exactly what I am doing here because I am pretty new to C++.

I have a main class that creates a manager for GUI items. The manager will create the GUI items and update them etc.

The GUI items have their own code that controls their own behavior. But for some things I would like to have a pointer to the GUI manager from these GUI items.

This means my GUI manager needs pointers of the items to be able to create the items. But those items also need a pointer to this manager.

Because it is not possible to include each other I only included the item inside the manager. Like this in the header file of the manager:

erGuiManager.h

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "erGuiItem.h"

class erGuiManager {
public:
    erGuiManager();

    void update();
    void draw();
    void setup();

    erGuiItem* btn;
};
```

I create items like this in the erGuiManager.cpp, and send a reference from the manager to the item.

```
#include "erGuiManager.h"

void erGuiManager::setup() {
    btn = new erGuiItem();
    btn->setup(this); //THE SETUP GETS A REFERENCE TO THE MANAGER
}

// and update them etc
```

Now I create a pointer to the manager in the erGuiItem.h, and I do not include the Manager.h, but I only declare it so the compiler knows it is a class:

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "ofImage.h"

class erGuiManager; //DECLARING THE MANAGER

class erGuiItem {

public:
    erGuiItem();
    void setup(erGuiManager* GuiManager);

protected:
    erGuiManager* GM;
    };
```

Then in the setup function I get the pointer send by the manager and declare it to the pointer in the erGuiItem.cpp:

```
#include "erGuiItem.h"

void erGuiItem::setup(erGuiManager* GuiManager) {
    GM = GuiManager;
}

void erGuiItem::update() {
    GM->somevariable = variable; //HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
}
```

Then I try to do something with this pointer to the manager somewhere in my code from my item, as you can see above. And that is where I get the error **Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed..**

Now I know where this problem is coming from, I only declared the class erGuiManager, and I did not define it properly. But I have no clue how to do this otherwise. Normally I would have to #include the manager to fix this, but because the manager already includes erGuiItem, I can't.

Can someone explain to me how to-do this properly?

I will keep searching for a solution, if I find one myself I will post it here. Thanks for any help in advance!

Alexander

Comment: headers can't include each other but cpp can include thier associated header each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *erGuiItem.cpp* you `#include "erGuiManager.h"`.

Comment: A yes thanks! I tried that before, but without declaring (class erGuiManager;) in ( "erGuiItem.h") ....

Thanks for clearing that up!